# Is it necessary to normalize matrices before diagonalizing for the eigendecomposition?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have a matrix A: \begin{bmatrix}3/4&0&-1/4\\0&1&0\\-1/4&0&3/4\end{bmatrix}

and a matrix B = $\lim_{k→∞} A^k$

I've retrieved the eigenvalues and eigenvectors and I want to compute B as a numerical matrix. I did a diagonalisation on symbolab so I can use the eigendecomposition and it took the eigenvector matrix to be:

\begin{bmatrix}0&-1&1\\1&0&0\\0&1&1\end{bmatrix}

However when I calculated it on paper, I took the normalised ones as the question asked for an orthogonal matrix, and the standard eigenvector matrix was not orthogonal (I think).

\begin{bmatrix}-1/\sqrt{2}&0&1/\sqrt{2}\\0&1&0\\1/\sqrt{2}&0&1/\sqrt{2}\end{bmatrix}

Is that a necessary step? Or should I not use the normalised version?

Comment: it's going to be a lot easier to complete the calculation if you use the normalized matrix, which should be orthogonal since the original matrix is symmetric

Comment: thank you david! i was worried that mine wouldn't be ok to use. i'll continue with the normalised one :)